# Set the focus on the first input element with error message and set the tab of the TabStrip containing it to active

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a form with some input fields. I am using the tabStrip KendoUI widget to group the input fields. I am using the Kendo validator and when the form is submitted some error messages are triggered. The problem is that if the input field with the error message is on a different tab then the currently selected the user cannot see it. What I want to accomplish is when the form is validated the tab containing the first input field with error message to be selected and the focus to be on that input field. Here is some sample code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tabStrip").kendoTabStrip();
</script>

<div id="tabStrip">
    <ul>
        <li class="k-state-active">Master Info</li>
        <li>Developer Info</li>
    </ul>
     <div id="tabStrip-1">
         <div>
            <label for="folderName" class="required">Folder Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="folderName" name="folderName"  required />
            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="folderName"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="afk">Afk:</label>
            <input type="text" id="afk" name="afk" data-bind = "value: Afk" />
        </div>
     </div>
     <div id="tabStrip-2">
         <div>
            <label for="updateFolder" class="required">Update Folder:</label>
            <input type="text" id="Text1" name="updateFolder" class="k-input k-invalid" required />
            <span class="k-invalid-msg" data-for="updateFolder"></span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="age">Age:</label>
            <input type="text" id="age" name="age" class="k-input k-invalid" data-bind = "value: Age" />
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

My idea is to take all the input fields that are in div with id="tabStrip-1" and check if they contain `class="k-input k-invalid"` which as far as I understand is applied to the input field when there is a validation error. If the input field contains the class I will change the id of the tab to be this one and set the focus on that element. If all fields are valid I will do the same with the next tab, I tried this with Jquery to take the input elements and foreach them but my skills in web development are very poor and I did not succeed. I think my approach will work though. Any help with working example or suggestions for better approach will be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the kendoTabStrip but this code will get you the id of the first tab strip containing an error.

```
​
//Select all the tab strips
tabs = $("#tabStrip").find('div[id^=tabStrip]');
first_error_id = "";
//Loop through the tab strips looking for an input containing the error class
for(var i = 0; i < tabs.length; i+=1){
    if ($(tabs[i]).find('input.k-input.k-invalid').length > 0) {
        first_error_id = tabs[i].id;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The selector for the first `input` field with the required classes would be:

```
$('input.k-input.k-invalid:first').focus();
```

I am, however, unsure what you mean by "If the input field contains the class I will change the id of the tab to be this one."

Comment: Well, If the currently active tab is the first one and the error message is on an input field in the second tab, I should change the active tab to be the second tab otherwise the user will not be able to see the error message.

Comment: Thank You David for your help. This works if I use $(document).ready(function () but if I try to set focus on the element after submit nothing happens, I think the DOM element is not loaded yet. How can I check if the element is loaded and then set the focus on it? Maybe I should ask the question in another thread ...